# I am trying to copy a file, but getting error message

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres, probably missing something silly like (the correct name of my directory). Can someone guide me?

I am following book instructions, Practical SQL by Anthony DeBarros

Code:

```
copy us_counties_2010 from  'C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv' with (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

Error:

> ERROR:  could not open file
> "C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv" for reading:
> Permission denied HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server
> process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as
> psql's \copy. SQL state: 42501
>
> copy us_counties_2010 from
> 'C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv' with (FORMAT
> CSV, HEADER);

Expected:

> Query returned successfully: 3143 rows affected

Actual:

> ERROR:  could not open file
> "C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv" for reading:
> Permission denied HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server
> process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as
> psql's \copy. SQL state: 42501

Comment: `copy table_name (column1,...) from 'C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;` is this what you want?

Comment: From error i think you are running this not in psql?

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this on MacOS  Sonoma v.14.2.1 ? I have given all the permissions needed to pgAdmin but nothing seems to work. Still same error.

Answer (score 24):

All that is to be done is:
Go to *Properties* of that particular file by right clicking on it. Then, go to *Security* tab of the displayed Properties dialog box. Click on *Edit* option. *Permissions* dialog box appears, then click on *Add* button. Type '**Everyone**' (without apostrophes) in the *"Enter the object names to select"* description box and click on *OK* button. Then, make sure all the checkboxes of *"Permissions for Everyone"* are selected by just ticking the *"Full Control"* check box to allow the control access without any restriction. Then, *Apply* and *OK* all the tabs to apply all the changes done.

You can now run/execute the query without any errors.

Comment: This is the answer we need.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: There is no "Security" option, in Windows 11.

Answer (score 9):

As the message tells you, Postres is not allowed to read the file.

If you want to fix that open the Task Manager, and click on "Show processes from all users". Look for the rows with the image name `postgres.exe` (likely more than one). Remember the value in the column "User Name" (it's probably `NETWORK SERVICE`). Open the properties of your file, add that user in the "Security" tab and grant read access to them.

Or use  `psql`'s `\copy` as the message suggests.

Answer (score 4):

```
copy us_counties_2010 (your column name)//(country_code, latitude, longitude, country, population)
 FROM 'D:\us_counties_2010 .csv' DELIMITER ',' csv HEADER
```

Your csv file should be in other than C drive. It can't access your C drive. Store it in D drive or any other it will work perfect.

Comment: COPY vessel_types FROM 'D:\vessel_types.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
It still doesn't work. pgAdmin 4 v8.1 , PostgreSQL v16.1, Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

Change the Location of data file and path to Drive[**'D:\us_counties_2010.csv'** ] it will work.

The permission is denied because your files[us_counties_2010.csv] is in 'C' Drive ['C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv'] which is a Windows Drive and permissions are restricted and may not be changed easily & impossible without administrative privileges.

Good Luck & happy programming!

Comment: COPY vessel_types FROM 'D:\vessel_types.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER; It still doesn't work for me. pgAdmin 4 v8.1 , PostgreSQL v16.1, Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

In the case when creating a table as well as importing data from a CSV file, we can skip the query and use the program itself. To do this, simply right-click on your table in the tree on the left and select the Import/Export… menu item.

[image: importing csv file using postgresql]

A window will appear with the slider set to Import. Then select the source file and set the format to CSV. Set the Header to Yes if your file has a header. The only thing left is to select the delimiter (usually a comma).

When you click OK, the data will be imported.

For a better understanding, you can refer original article.
https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-import-csv-to-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PSQL, run it as administrator, then you shouldn't have any problem when you are using COPY

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for anyone who may face the same problem follow this steps exactly as they are ---

1. right-click the folder you want to save your data into, say "D:\documents\smartguy\new_data\tasting_salt.csv", **in this case right-click the new data folder**
2. Click *Properties*, and click the *Security* tab.
3. Click *Edit* and then *Add*.
4. Type the name **Everyone** into the object names box and click OK.
5. Highlight *Everyone* in the user list, select all boxes under *Allow*,
   and then click *Apply* and *OK*.

Should look like below.[image: How the properties setting should appear]

Answer (score -2):

```sql
copy us_counties_2010 from  'C:\Users\obella\OneDrive\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv' with (FORMAT CSV, HEADER,DELIMITER ',');
```

Use this code instead of that