# How to import a CSV file into PostgreSQL using Mac

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into PostgreSQL using pgAdmin. However, I am getting an error message when attempting to perform a COPY command.

ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/brandoncruz/Desktop/Test File.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501

Below is the code I have attempted to use for the import.

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
role_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
role_name VARCHAR (255)
);       

COPY roles FROM '/Users/brandoncruz/Desktop/Test File.csv'  DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to copy a file, but getting error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031813/i-am-trying-to-copy-a-file-but-getting-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

It looks about your permissions. You can change permissions of  'Test File.csv'. I mean Postgres user cannot read your file. After change permissions it must be copied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check following path if you are using pgAdmin:
pgAdmin > File > Preferences
Paths > Binary Paths
For postgreSQL binary path, you should find the location of PostgreSQL from your mac and save that:
i.e. C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin (Windows)
For mac, check under Applications, Program Files, that depends and changes from Mac to Mac.